# Activity null in fragment because recreate()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, fragment

My apps is creating with `fragments` handle by `ViewPager`. And I use the page 2 of the `ViewPager` to be the theme menu.

I change the theme using `sharedPreference` and `recreate();` the fragment in page 2.

My Problem is, page 2 has `animation`, after change `recreate();` from page 2, the `animation` won't work because the `animation` need `activity` to show it.

I have tried to use `startActivity()`, the page return to page 1 (means the first page)

Is there anyway to get back the activity?

Or is there anyway to implement **change theme** page to have `animation`?